# How to manage exceptions thrown from Result.Map delegate?

Tags: c#, language-ext

The code for [LanguageExt.Common.Result.Map](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/d42c12a2c09bc04f9185587fd4f74bafa27d987f/LanguageExt.Core/Common/Result/Result.cs#L175) is as follow:

```
[Pure]
public Result<B> Map<B>(Func<A, B> f) =>
    IsFaulted 
        ? new Result<B>(Exception)
        : new Result<B>(f(Value));
```

How to manage the scenario where the `Func f` might throw an error too?

For example, let's say I have this:

```
public Result<string> DoFirst()
{
    return Result<string>("Good");
}

public Result<int> DoNext()
{
    var result = DoFirst();

    return result.Map<int>(_ =>
    {
        try
        {
            // Some unsafe code that will eventually
            // throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return 200;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // return Result<int>(ex); // Not allowed, must return an int
            // return ex; // Not allowed, must return an int
        }
    });
}
```

What happens if the Exception is not handled?

It seems like we are missing a `FlatMap` method or something like that, or May be I am not using the right Class.

######### ADDED #########

FlatMap could look like this:

```
[Pure]
public Result<B> FlatMap<B>(Func<A, Result<B>> f) =>
    IsFaulted 
        ? new Result<B>(Exception)
        : f(Value);
```

That would have solved my issue. Should I create a pull request?

Comment: Did the `Result` come from a `Try` or something like that? You should `Map` *that* instead of consuming the `Result<T>` directly.

Comment: Okay, this is the second time that I have received that recommendation. I will just switch to a `Try`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Try<T>` monad for that indeed

```cs
public string DoFirst()
{
  // Exceptions thrown here will be handled by the Try monad
  return "Good";
}

public int DoNext(string s)
{  
  // Exceptions thrown here will be handled by the Try monad
  return 200;
}

public void Run() 
{
  Prelude
    .Try(() => DoFirst())
    .Map(s => DoNext(s))
    .Match(
      i => { /* Do something with the result */ },
      ex => { /* Do something with the exception */ }
    );
}
```

Hope this helps a little

Comment: Yes, I finally used `Try/TryAsync<T>`